# Differential effect of brief power outage on PCs

Tags: power

Let me open with an apology if this is not the appropriate forum.

I have two PCs connected to the same power strip. One is an older tower PC and the other is a new all-in-one. Both run Windows 10 if that matters.

Overnight, there was a brief power interruption, possibly just a few seconds.

This morning, I noticed that the new PC recorded an unexpected shutdown event, but the old PC did not--it appeared not to have been affected.

Is there something about the different electronics that might account for one PC shutting down and the other one not?

Thanks!

(P.S. I did look around for a while on the internet, but I didn't see anything about this question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All power supplies have input and output capacitors, thus they can withstand a brief period of input power interruption without shutting down the computer. In fact, the minimal power loss hold-up time is standardized and all PCs must meet the requirements.

Thus, if there's a difference, the reason must be:

1. The power supply may have used a larger capacitor than the other, or the power consumption of one PC is lower so the same capacitance can last longer, or a combination of both. The result is that one PC's power loss hold-up time meets and exceeds the standard.
2. Less likely, it's also possible that another PC's hold-up time does not meet the standard, possibly due to an oversight or due to capacitor aging.

According to your description, (1) is the more likely scenario.

### ATX specification

In [Desktop Platform Form Factors Power Supply - Design Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/guides/power-supply-design-guide-june.pdf) (a.k.a. The "ATX" spec) by Intel, page 20 and 21, the required hold-up time after a power interruption is specified.

> **3.2.9 Voltage Hold-Up Time** - Required.
> The power supply should maintain output regulations per Table 3-2 despite a loss of input power at the low-end nominal range- 115 VAC / 47 Hz or 230 VAC / 47 Hz – at maximum continuous output load as applicable for a minimum of 17ms (T5+T6).
>
> [image: ATX power timing diagram]
> Parameter:
>
> - T5 - AC loss to PWR_OK hold-up time: > 16 ms
> - T6 - PWR_OK inactive to DC loss delay: > 1 ms

To rephrase it, when the AC line voltage is interrupted, the +12 V, +5 V, and +3.3 V output rails start to fall. For a properly designed, ATX-compliant power supply, the power supply should hold up for at least 16 ms before the `PWR_OK` (a.k.a the well-known Power Good) signal becomes `LOW`, telling the motherboard that it has failed. Furthermore, even after `PWR_OK` becomes `LOW`, it's also required that all output voltage rails continue to hold up for at least 1 milliseconds before they has fallen below the 95% threshold of their nominal output voltages.

Here's some actual oscilloscope screenshots showing the response of a consumer-grade 650 W ATX power supply after the loss of AC input under full load.

[image: Oscilloscope screetshot, Power-Good measured]

<sub>Source: [fcpowerup.com](https://www.fcpowerup.com/coolermaster-mwe-gold-v2-650w/),  fair use. *Note: this is a cool Chinese PC review website which conducts independent verification of consumer PSUs according to the full ATX specs.*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The power supply design and size plus the system power consumption. If you've sat through a split second brownout you may notice your lights blink but your PC stays the same due to the large capacitors in the power supply and associated power conditioning. The higher your PSU capacity (which has correlation with the size of capacitors used) and the lower the power consumption of your system relative to that, the longer it can hold out.